# How to pg_restore some tables with automatic index creation?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13, pg-restore

How to restore some table from pg_dump custom format, and automatically create it's index ?

I just restore some tables from database dump (custom format).

`pg_restore -d database --table=table1 --table=table2 --table=table3 dumpdatabase.dmp`

This result tables with no index. I have to create manually each of them. How to automatically create it's index with pg_restore command ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do that. The best you can do is to create a table of contents with

```bash
pg_restore -l -f toc dumpdatabase.dmp
```

Then edit `toc` and delete everything except the lines for the table and its indexes. Then you can restore only these objects with

```bash
pg_restore -L toc -d somedatabase -U postgres dumpdatabase.dmp
```